# Problems trying to move my /home partition

Tags: 10.10, encryption, home-directory, rsync, partitioning

I was running low in disk space on my Linux box, Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop, (specifically on my /home partition) so I added another disk to it and I am trying to move the home partition into it.

I am trying to follow the steps on this guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

However, when copying the files over to the new mounted partition rsync seems to fail silently. When I compare the folders, the new one is still empty.

This is the command that I am executing:

```
sudo rsync -axS --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/home/.
```

Has it anything to do with the encryption on my home folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-if your home directory is encryted, follow the guide by Joao as answer to question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17332/how-can-i-move-an-encrypted-home-directory-to-another-partition)

-otherwise if your home directory is not encrypted just follow the advice in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5484/how-can-i-move-my-home-directory-to-another-partition-if-its-already-part-of-th)