# Some files not copied when moving an encrypted home to a different partition

Tags: 10.04, encryption, ecryptfs

I have "successfully" moved my encrypted home to a separate partition using the instructions here:
[How can i move an encrypted home directory to another partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17332/how-can-i-move-an-encrypted-home-directory-to-another-partition)

However, some files are not being copied over. Most notably, I have a directory in my old home that contains the themes I use. This directory and it's contents are not copied over to the new home and therefore I come up with the default theme. Permissions on the directory that was not moved are identical to the other directories in home. Another discrepancy is that my Dropbox folder came over empty and had to resync itself. My concern is what else might be missing from the copied home. At this point, I've flipped back to the old home by re-editing /etc/fstab, but I'd really like to get /home cleanly and completely off of root without having to core the system.

Comment: the problem is rsync cannot copy certain files with special characters see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/rsync-cant-copy-certain-files-with-unusual-characters-while-cp-can-827462/

Comment: Unfortunately, special characters in the directory of file names does not appear to be the case. There are only alphabetic characters in the directory name (fine, it's named Themes) and the files inside are all _file-name_.tar.gz

Any other ideas?

Comment: There's no fool like an old fool. Using the second solution in the "how can I move..." link referred to in the original question solves the problem. Thanks for the additional information though, Jorge.

Answer (score 1):

OP found the answer in the other askubuntu link : [How can i move an encrypted home directory to another partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17332/how-can-i-move-an-encrypted-home-directory-to-another-partition)

> Using the second solution in the "how can I move..." link referred to in the original question solves the problem.