# kubuntu move encrypted home dir to new SSD (keep encryption)

Tags: kubuntu, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs, directory

I already found how to move my encrypted home dir to new hd, but I have a comprehension question.
So when I installed kubuntu 11.10 I choose to have an encryption (I think there was only possible to choose if the home is encrypted, anyway I choose encryption), so my /home has the following structure:

```
/home/.ecryptfs
/home/<my_username>/.ecryptfs (only link to /home/.ecryptfs/<my_username>/.ecryptfs)
/home/<my_username>/.Private (only link to /home/.ecryptfs/<my_username>/.Private)
```

This should be the solution:
[How can i move an encrypted home directory to another partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17332/how-can-i-move-an-encrypted-home-directory-to-another-partition)

I couldn't follow up cause probably it was too old. So the point is, my new place should be a new SSD which I added to the system, formatted with ext4. What I don't understand is, is this sufficient, in order to keep my encryption, or should I do something to encrypt my new formatted SSD and then do the howto?

Thanks a lot?

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep your encryption, you simply need to ensure that **all** of the data that was previously in `/home` is copied over to your new `/home`.  That includes `/home/$USERNAME` as well as `/home/.ecryptfs`.

You don't need to encrypt your new formatted SSD.

Comment: how can I enter the new mount point to my new encrypted home, i mean are there any special options that I have to define or something? In my `/etc/fstab` file I just have: `UUID=<uuid> /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`. I didn't have separate mount points to `home` `usr` etc.