# Issue moving my encrypted home directory on a new drive

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, encryption, ecryptfs, transfer

I have installed a second hard drive on my computer (mounted as `/media/<my-user-name>/hd2`) with one partition only. I'd like to move my home folder on this new drive.
 Being logged on my admin session, I'm following the procedure explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17364/498358) of the question [How can i move an encrypted home directory to another partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17332/498358).

So I successively entered following commands in my terminal:

```
ecryptfs-umount-private
chown $USER /media/<my-user-name>/hd2/$USER
sudo rsync -aP --progress --stats $HOME/.Private $HOME/.ecryptfs /media/<my-user-name>/hd2/$USER
```

However, I got this message:

```
[sudo] password for <my-user-name>: 
sending incremental file list

Number of files: 2 (link: 2)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 57 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 134
Total bytes received: 12

sent 134 bytes  received 12 bytes  292.00 bytes/sec
total size is 57  speedup is 0.39
```

Since I've 30+ Gio data in my home directory, it seems they have not been copied on the new drive.

However, I don't know what I'm not doing correctly. Could you please help me?

Comment: Never used rsync but I wonder If there should be 1 source directory and 1 target directory. You appear to have 2 source directories?

Comment: The same happens when entering `sudo rsync -aP --progress --stats $HOME/.Private /media/ebo/hd2/$USER && sudo rsync -aP --progress --stats $HOME/.ecryptfs /media/ebo/hd2/$USER`...